# Add a class to dynamically added template element

Tags: django

I'm using the [urlize filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#urlize) in some user submitted content, however I would like to add a class to to the anchor element that is rendered.

Django is currently rendering

```
www.someurl.com
```

as

```
<a href="www.someurl.com">www.someurl.com</a>
```

But I want it to render it as

```
<a class="myClass" href="www.someurl.com">www.someurl.com</a>
```

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a custom template filter to add class to the rendered element.

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter(is_safe=True)
def class_to_url(value):
    return value.replace('<a ', "<a class='myClass' ">)
```

And then use it in your template with urlize:

```
{{ text_url|urlize|class_to_url }}
```

See [django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#registering-custom-filters) for custom template tags and filters

Comment: It's actually returning escaped html, how do I prevent that?

Comment: You can mark the value as safe by passing `is_safe` arg to `filter()`. Check the updated answer.